# Splitting data between worksheets depending on status of Column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have been asked to create a database of volunteers in Excel. The main worksheet (called Data) holds all the information – names, addresses, numbers, reference checks, placements, supervisors, etc.  What I am trying to achieve is for the relevant information to be moved from one worksheet to another when the status of the person changes.
There would be 5 categories which the volunteers would fall under (column A labelled ‘Status’)

PROCESSING

ACTIVE

ON HOLD

BARRED

STOPPED/RETIRED

What I want to get is a live database so the information would appear on a relevant worksheet whenever the status on the main spreadsheet changes , but I only want some information to show depending on the category…
Each Worksheet would contain columns A-F from the ‘Data’ worksheet and in addition:

Processing would contain columns X-AE

Active: AF-AW

On Hold: AZ-BC

Barred: AX-AY

Stopped/Retired:- BD-BH

I have searched and searched again but I know nothing about Macros (and my IT department is unable to help) So my question is – is this doable and if so is anyone able to help me? 
I hope I am making sense and if not I can email across the dummy database with some made up names to show what it is I am trying to create

Comment: Can you show us generally what you want to do? I'm having difficulties understanding why you want the additional status data in those specific columns.

Comment: So you want five additional sheets, each displaying a different subset of the volunteers, which update automatically when volunteers are added / removed or their status is changed? If so, whilst it is technically possible in Excel, it will be extremely involved and very sluggish to run. I'd suggest an Access database if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using array formulae. This link shows [a simple example](https://blog.udemy.com/vlookup-multiple-values/) which provides the basic formula (explained in detail in the linked article)

```
=INDEX(range,SMALL(IF(col=value,ROW(range)),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A2))
```

Where `range` is the range of all your data from your main worksheet and `value` is the value you want to screen for (this changes for each of your sheets) and `col` is the column on your main sheet that you want to check the values of. Note it is an array forumla so you have to press control+shift+enter after typing in the formula as explained at the bottom of the link.

You will notice that I have changed the formula to say `COLUMN(A2)` instead of `2`. This is so that you can drag the formula across the columns as well as down the rows. You might need to make this `COLUMN(A2)-x` where `x` is an offset because your data don't start in column A.

Note that the same applies for the `ROW(1:1)` part, if your `range` doesn't start in row 1 then you will need to offset this by some value as well (i.e. something like `ROW(1:1)-y`)